# An Optimal Strategy for a Coin Flipping Game

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider a fair coin, tossed 100 times to create a sequence of $H$s and $T$s.

A participant is allowed to ask 1 yes or no question (e.g. was the first coin flip heads?), then plays a game where he tries to guess all 100 coins. The participant is awarded $\$1$ for every coin guessed correctly, and loses $\$1$ for each incorrect guess. Find and prove an optimal strategy for the player.

I have a hunch that the optimal strategy may be to ask "Were there more heads than tails?" and then, depending on the answer, proceed to guess either all $H$s or all $T$s. With this strategy, the player is guaranteed nonnegative earnings, and I believe the expected value is $$\sum_{i=0}^{50}{\binom{100}{i}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{99}(100-2i)} \approx \$7.96$$

I've confirmed the expected value with a Monte-Carlo simulation in Python, but I'm having trouble proving that this is optimal.

My best attempt to translate this into more rigorous mathematics is to consider the yes/no question as a partition. Let $X$ be the set of $2^{100}$ possible sequences and $x$ be the sequence rolled. A yes/no question will always partition the set into two. Suppose that set $A$ is the set of all sequences in which the answer to our question is "yes", then the expected value of our game would be $$E[G] = \frac{|A|}{2^{100}}E[G|x\in A]\space + \left(1-\frac{|A|}{2^{100}}\right)E[G|x \notin A],$$

where G is the expected value of the game, playing with some optimal strategy. I've also made the note that given any specific set $A$, $x \in A$ implies there is an optimal (but not necessarily unique) guess. For instance, if we know that there are more heads than tails, a sequence of 100 $H$s is an optimal guess.

Comment: Is this Google/Facebook job interview by any chance?

Comment: It's inspired by one. The original question simply awards the player $1 for guessing the entire sequence correctly, after one yes or no question. This version rewards the player based on each coin guessed correctly.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but are you informed after each guess whether you guessed correctly, or are you told at the end how much you won/lost?

Comment: @VarunVejalla Somewhat counterintuitively, I argue it actually won't matter! While the set of possible "guessing strategies" is more complicated if you can observe all the flips you've guessed so far, my answer doesn't change: your guess for the next flip if the answer were "yes" must be the opposite of your guess if the answer were "no" (in order for your guessing strategy to be optimal). Any such guessing strategy will give the same expected payoff as any other when you choose the optimal corresponding question. His strategy still satisfies this property despite not depending on past flips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your construction is optimal! Suppose there are $N$ flips (e.g. $N=100$).

I have two proofs:

1. A simple logical proof that gives a sufficient condition for optimality.
2. A more involved mathematical proof that gives necessary and sufficient conditions.

Both of them involve the same setup.

---

### Setup

Denote a guessing strategy $G = (G_{yes}, G_{no})$ where $G_{yes}, G_{no} \in \{ H, T \}^{N}$ characterizes your guess when the answer is "yes" or "no" (irrespective of the question asked). Denote the question $Q$ as a subset of the power set of $\{ H, T \}^{N}$ and the expected payoff by $S(G,Q)$.

Fix any $G$, the optimal question $Q_{G}$ is whether $G_{yes}$ leads to a strictly higher payoff than $G_{no}$?  Any other question can only lead to a lower expected payoff by sometimes resulting in the worse guess. (The optimal question is unique up to how ties between the payoff of $G_{yes}$ and $G_{no}$ are included in the question. Here, $Q_{G}$ is constructed so that all ties are answered "no.")

Denote the expected payoff when the optimal question is asked by $S^{*}(G)=S(G,Q_{G})$. Notice it is much easier to choose two sequences of flips ($G$) than to choose any subset of all such flips ($Q$)!

Lemma: $S^{*}(G)$ only depends on the number of flips ($N$) and the number of flips for which $G_{yes}$ and $G_{no}$ differ ($n$).

Proof: Suppose $G_{yes}$ and $G_{no}$ differ for exactly $n$ flips, then any other guess $\hat{G}_{yes}$ and $\hat{G}_{no}$ that differs for exactly $n$ flips can be generated from $G$ by relabelling the sides of each coin flip.

---

### Sufficient Condition

Result: Increasing the number of flips for which $G_{yes}$ and $G_{no}$ differ weakly increases the expected payoff.

Proof: If $G_{yes}$ and $G_{no}$ are the same for flip $k$, then flip $k$ is *independent* of the answer to question $Q_{G}$ since it doesn't change the relative payoffs. Let $\hat{G} = (\hat{G}_{yes},G_{no})$ where $\hat{G}_{yes}$ is the same as $G_{yes}$ but for flip $k$, then $\hat{G}$ gives the same expected payoff as $G$ when question $Q_{G}$ is asked, therefore:
$$S^{*}(G) = S(G,Q_{G}) = S(\hat{G},Q_{G}) \leq S(\hat{G},Q_{\hat{G}}) = S^{*}(\hat{G})$$

(Note that our specific construction of $Q_{G}$ was needed to say flip $k$ is *independent* of the answer to question $Q_{G}$.) Therefore, a sufficient condition is that the guesses differ on every flip. This may not be necessary because increasing the number of flips for which $G_{yes}$ and $G_{no}$ differ only ***weakly*** increases the expected payoff.

Sufficient Condition: $S^{*}(G)$ is maximized if $G_{yes}$ and $G_{no}$ are different for every flip.

---

### Necessary and Sufficient Condition

Lemma: Let $n$ denote number of coin flips for which $G_{yes}$ and $G_{no}$ differ, then:

$$S^{*}(G) = N/2 + \mathbb{E}|X_{n}-n/2|$$

Where $X_{n} \sim \text{Binomial}(n,1/2)$.

Proof: The probability of correctly guessing any coin flip where $G_{yes}$ and $G_{no}$ agree is $1/2$. Consider the $n$ coin flips where $G_{yes}$ and $G_{no}$ are different, if $X_{n}$ of these flips agree with $G_{yes}$ then $n-X_{n}$ flips agree with $G_{no}$, thus:

$$
\begin{align}
S^{*}(G) &= (N-n)/2 + \mathbb{E}\left[\max(X_{n}, n-X_{n})\right] \\
&=N/2 + \mathbb{E}|X_{n}-n/2|
\end{align}$$

---

This expression strictly increases when $n$ increases by one from even to odd but is constant when $n$ increases by one from odd to even. (Source: "A Derivation of the Mean Absolute Distance in One-Dimensional Random Walk" by Hižak and Logożar, Tehnički glasnik 2011.) This relationship between $S^{*}$ and $n$ implies the following result:

***Result: If $N$ is odd, $S^{*}(G)$ is maximized if and only if $G_{yes}$ and $G_{no}$ differ for every flip. If $N$ is even, $S^{*}(G)$ is maximized if and only if $G_{yes}$ and $G_{no}$ are the same for at most one flip.

---

### If $N=100$

Your $G_{yes}$ is all heads and $G_{no}$ all tails, so it satisfies this property, and your question is optimal: does $G_{yes}$ give strictly higher payoff than $G_{no}$? In other words, are there strictly more than $50$ heads?

Because $N$ is even, any other pair of guesses that are the same for at most one flip would also correspond to an optimal strategy.

Comment: Fascinating solution! One thing that I found slightly confusing was how $A_G$ and $G$ were defined. It seems that $G$ is defined to be a guessing strategy determined by $A$. That is, for every $A$, we can come up with an optimal $G_{yes}$ and $G_{no}$. But, we define $A_G$ using $G_{yes}$ and $G_{no}$.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the second sentence now if that is clearer? The general idea is itself kind of confusing, haha! I'm asking you to choose a guessing strategy before your question.

Comment: There is something wrong with this solution, since optimality characterization is not fully right; the strategies of asking (H,H) vs (T,T) have the same expected return as (H,H) vs (T,H). Also, I am not sure if I buy the argument in (1) about G hat having a higher payoff, since now this change can influence which answer is picked. I still like the overall argument and the constructions though, so hopefully these are minor errors, and will refrain from -1 ing it for now.

Comment: Thanks, you're right that (H,H) vs (T,T) has the same expected payoff as (H,H) vs (T,H), which contradicts the "only if" part of my result. I think the reason for this your next point. Since $\hat{G}$ gives the same expected payoff as $G$ when question $A_{G}$ is asked, $\hat{G}$ must give at least as high of an expected payoff when the optimal question $A_{\hat{G}}$ is asked. Does that part makes sense? What your example shows is that this payoff need not be *strictly* higher. I either need to remove the "only if" parts or figure out conditions under which it is strict.

Comment: @E-A I've edited the answer accordingly--let me know if anything is still particularly unclear, thanks!

Comment: I would remove the sequential one; say the question is "Are there more heads than tails?" and the answer is yes, so you start guessing "heads", and you see 49 tails. Now, both G_yes and G_no hopefully have "heads" remaining for both G_yes and G_no. Thanks for fixing the sufficiency/necessity (particularly the inequality is quite clear).