# Calculating expected value of the return for 100 fair coins with a single constraint?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

There are 100 coins and someone flips them and doesn't tell us the results. I can ask one Yes/No question. After the answer, I will start guessing the coin flip results. For each correct guess, I get 1 dollar and for each wrong guess, I lose 1 dollar. What is the best strategy to play this game and what is the maximum expected value of the return?

Note: I tried one approach where I will ask if heads were equal or more then tails? Then select heads if the answer is yes else tails. Tried to simulate the results and got a value approx 7.93. Thinking if there is a better approach to this problem to get a higher value of expected winnings.

Attaching my simulated results:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean, after the flips are done, but not revealed, I get to ask a single Yes/No question?  So, for example, I could ask "are there more than $50$ Heads?  And if the answer is Yes, I guess $H$ for every flip and if the answer is No I guess $T$ for every flip..which at least proves that the expected profit is positive.

Comment: @lulu I believe so. It's quite ambiguous; there could be an optimal strategy but it's really hard to predict the *maximum expected value* of the return.

Comment: Well, given any explicit strategy you should be able to compute it's expected return.  Barring arithmetic error, I see that my strategy is expected to win $7.9589$ which is really not bad. My guess is that this is optimal, but I don't see a proof of that.

Comment: It is an open ended question. If you decide to guess all of them the same, your chances of losing money is zero but your chances of making money is zero too. If you find whether there are more heads or tails by asking a Yes/No question and one is indeed more than the other, you make money.

Comment: @lulu : How do you reach this number of 7.95? Please explain

Comment: I think instead of asking a simple question like "Are there more head then tails, I  should take a more quantitative approach?

Comment: I just did it by hand (well, with a computer).  With my strategy, you always win $|100-2n|$ if there are exactly $n$ Heads, so I just computed $2^{-100}\times \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |100-2n|\binom {100}n$.

Comment: One reason to doubt that my method is strictly optimal is that it breaks even when there are exactly $50$ Heads.  That's a whole lot of cases that I make no money on.  So maybe there is a way to tighten the question so as to capture at least some of those cases.

Comment: Typo:  in my sum a couple of comments ago, the upper limit should be $100$, not $\infty$.

Comment: Similar question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3807744/an-optimal-strategy-for-a-coin-flipping-game)

Comment: Thanks a lot for link